# What's the difference between when, as, and while?

Tags: when

I think choices 1, 2, and 3 are correct. Is there any difference?

I saw a boy.........I was driving.

1)when     
2)as      
3)while   
4)since

Thanks

Comment: They're all legal grammatically, but #4 has a different meaning that doesn't totally make sense. The meanings of the words can be easily looked up in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further context, there is some ambiguity present with the choice of "when".  To say "I say a boy when I was driving." may be read as saying that you saw a boy during that time of your life when you were a driver.  It is not necessarily the case that you were in the act of driving at the time you saw the boy.

A similar problem arises with the choice of "while" since, again, "while I was driving" may simply refer to that time in your life when you were licensed to drive.

And again, with the choice of "since" the same ambiguity arises between being in the act of driving and simply being licensed to drive.

Therefore, I would suggest that "as" is the correct choice.

Comment: But there is ambiguity with ***as*** as well. Is it being used to mean *because* or *while*?

Comment: @Jim Excellent point.  I hadn't considered that.  If *as* is read to mean either *because* or *while*, then it would still imply that the boy was seen during the act of driving.  For example, you would not say "I saw the boy because I have a license to drive".  What do you think?

Comment: 'I saw a boy when I was driving' could well be my choice if there is a contrast with 'but nobody at all when my wife was driving'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth HaHa!

Comment: I'm sorry; that was a serious comment. I certainly wouldn't use 'as' in this example. Am I missing something?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have missed the English wit since I left London.

Comment: Ah, the hint of my wife's celerity. Apologies; it went over my head. But the choice of 'as' is not always the preferred one here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I would have used *when* if more context was provided, and I think it is fair to say there would be no ambiguity in ordinary conversation.  In fact, I'd say any but *since* would be ok.

Comment: I think "since" wouldn't be ambiguous. Meaning I saw the boy because I was the only person driving. Don't you think without context all choices would be correct? Even with the noun boy taking an indefinite article.

Comment: @Morteza I feel that the ambiguity carried by "since" is in it being read as either "since I have been licensed to drive" or "because I was driving".  The problem with the "because" reading is that it implies that the only reason I saw the boy was because I was driving.  In other words, had I been a passenger in the car or had I been walking, then I wouldn't have seen the boy. This doesn't match the intended meaning. Of course in ordinary conversation, any of the four choices would work perfectly well.  However, if we must choose one, then we must look for issues in the available choices.

Comment: @NWR I agree. Looks like without proper context, this question wouldn't make a good one.